# Shape of numpy array comparison with empty list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have some problems understanding how python/numpy is casting array shapes when comparing to an empty list - which as far as I understand - is an implicit (element wise) comparison with False.

In the following example the shape decreases by one in the last dimension, if it is not greater than 1.

```
z = N.zeros((2,2,1))
z == []

>> array([], shape=(2, 2, 0), dtype=bool)

z2 = N.zeros((2,2,2))
z2 ==[]

>> False
```

If, however, I compare with False directly, I get the expected output.

```
z = N.zeros((2,2,1))
(z == False).shape

>> (2, 2, 2)


z2 = N.zeros((2,2,2))
(z2 == False).shape

>> (2, 2, 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ordinary broadcasting at work. When you do

```
z = N.zeros((2,2,1))
z == []
```

`[]` is interpreted as an array of shape `(0,)`, and then the shapes are broadcast against each other:

```
(2, 2, 1)
vs    (0,)
```

Since `(0,)` is shorter than `(2, 2, 1)`, it gets expanded, as if the array were copied repeatedly:

```
   (2, 2, 1)
vs (2, 2, 0)
```

and since there's a 1 in the first shape and the other shape doesn't have a 1 there, the first shape gets "expanded" as if it were copied *zero* times:

```
   (2, 2, 0)
vs (2, 2, 0)
```

The comparison thus results in an array of booleans with shape `(2, 2, 0)`.

---

When `z` has shape `(2, 2, 2)`:

```
z2 = N.zeros((2,2,2))
z2 ==[]
```

broadcasting fails, since a length-2 axis and a length-0 axis can't be broadcast against each other. NumPy reports that it doesn't know how to perform the comparison:

```
>>> numpy.zeros([2, 2, 2]).__eq__([])
NotImplemented
```

The list doesn't know how either, so Python falls back on the default comparison by identity, and gets a result of `False`.

---

When you compare against `False`:

```
z = N.zeros((2,2,1))
(z == False).shape
```

`False` gets interpreted as an array of shape **`()`** - an empty shape! That gets broadcast out to shape `(2, 2, 1)`, as if copied out to an array full of `False`s, so the result has the same shape as `z`.

Comment: I always understood the broadcasting as expanding the output array to the maximal shape of both input arrays (if applicable). In this case that is not true. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Only size `1` dimensions are changed to match the other.  A size `2` is never expanded to match size `4`.   I would have described the broadcasting sequence as `(2,2,1),(0,)=>(2,2,1),(1,1,0)=>(2,2,0)`.  All the `1` have been changed.